# Excluding Environment Variables from ZSH Autocomplete

Tags: shell, environment-variables, zsh

Quick example:

```
~ $ wor<TAB>
~ $ WORDCHARS=                                                                                                                                                                                                             
WORDCHARS    WORKON_HOME  WORKON_HOME  workon
```

`workon` is the desired command. Is there a way to exclude the environment variables from auto-completing in ZSH?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't find such an option, but maybe you are helped, if your completion would be case sensitive. you can set this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
CASE_SENSITIVE="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR

Add this to your `~/.zshrc`

```
function _parameters() {}
```

---

Explanation:

In the zsh completion system every completable pattern is matched to some completion function. In the case where completion is invoked in the command position (in zsh lingo), zsh invokes the function associated with the special pattern `-command-`.

All completion patterns and functions are stored in the `_comps_` variable as an associative array. So, you can see which function is invoked for completing commands like this:

```
echo ${_comps[-command-]}
```

In my case the function is `_command_names`. If we take a look at the source code of this function,

```
whence -f _command_names
```

then you'll see all sources from which possible completions are gathered. It can be builtins, executables on the path, local executables if the completion prefix contains a slash, aliases, functions, jobs, reserved words and, crucially, parameters, which includes environment variables. Looking at the code of `_command_names` I see that whether parameters should be suggested or not was not made configurable - the `_parameters` function is always invoked. The `_parameters` function likewise doesn't seem sufficiently configurable.

At this point we know enough to look at a few solutions. One would be to modify `_command_names` and remove the `parameters:_parameters` sources. Another is to make the `_parameters` function a no-op. The second option looks less error-prone and is therefore my recommendation.

---

Note that overriding the `_parameters` function also disables completion environment variables in other places (e.g., typing `$` and then hit Tab). To allow completing environment variables in other places, patching `_parameters` instead of overriding it is a possible solution. Here is an example:

```
autoload +X _parameters # load it for patching latter
functions[_parameters]="
[[ \$curcontext = -command- ]] && return
$functions[_parameters]"
```

It skips processing environment variables if `$curcontext`, the context for the called completion function, is in the program name. Escaping it is needed to make expanding `$curcontext` happens until the patched function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide parameters in the command position, so use [`tag-order`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-tag_002dorder_002c-completion-style):

```
zstyle ':completion:*:-command-:*' tag-order '!parameters'
```

The `!parameters` part says to hide parameters when the completion is in `-command-` position:

> ! tags...
>
> A string starting with an exclamation mark specifies names of tags that are not to be used. The effect is the same as if all other possible tags for the context had been listed.